# How to take the nylon strap out of a lock mounting bracket

Tags: lock

I am trying to attach the following bike-lock mounting bracket to a bike frame, but the nylon strap is already fastened inside the metal teeth. Is there a way to loosen the fastening mechanism without cutting the strap, so I can reuse the bracket?

[image]

I cannot find the exact model number of this bike-lock component, but it is similar to “Kryptonite Transit FlexFrame-U Bracket Bike Lock Mount” [https://www.amazon.com/Kryptonite-Transit-Flexframe-U-Bicycle-Bracket/dp/B005YPKLLE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005YPKLLE). I watched the installation instructions

but it does not show how to uninstall or loosen the strap. This Quara answer https://qr.ae/pKLss6 to "How do I remove a kryptonite bike lock mount?" claims that "As the straps have to be cut off the mount, it is not likely that you can re-use it on another bike." This forum https://www.bikeforums.net/general-cycling-discussion/496370-removing-onguard-u-lock-mounting-bracket.html suggests to apply brutal force via a wrench to pull out the strap, but my strap moved no distance. Google search by the image did not point to an exact match. My bracket is different in that it has a cylinder bolt with teeth inside to fasten the strap.

[image] [image]

I used a hexagonal wrench to loosen the bolt. While the bolt did rotate counterclockwise a little, the strap was not loosened. I wonder if the strap can be taken out of the bolt, so I can move it on.

Comment: Can you push the toothed plate back away from the strap, using a metal pick, a slice of stiff plastic, or something similar ?   I'm guessing its all a security feature.